# RCP Eclipse Platform Upgrade Issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am upgrading Eclipse platform for RCP product from 4.6.3 to 4.15. I am using Eclipse-SDK-4.15 for development and eclipse 4.15 based target platform and Java 8. I have resolved all the compilation errors in workspace. I am using existing launch configuration where "Execution Environment" is set as "JavaSE-1.8" and in Plug-ins tab "all workspace and enabled target plug-ins" is selected. On running the configuration I get below error:

```
!SESSION 2022-03-01 05:42:37.611 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=8.0.6.15 - pwa6480sr6fp15-20200724_01(SR6 FP15)
JRE 1.8.0 Windows Server 2016 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20200724_452227 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 4ce4b9d
OMR      - 08b0594
IBM      - 70917a2
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rmc.rcp.ui.75.composer
Command-line arguments:  -product com.ibm.rmc.rcp.ui.75.composer -data E:\Test\workspace/../runtime-rmc.product -dev file:E:/Test/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/rmc.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.508
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.4.500.v20200225-0827 [2]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.508
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917 [3]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.508
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.6.100.v20191001-1333 [4]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.apache.felix.scr; bundle-version="[2.1.0,3.0.0)"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.524
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.4.500.v20200225-0827.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.524
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/equinox/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.524
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/equinox/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.6.100.v20191001-1333.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/equinox/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi_[3.13.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/equinox/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.6.100.v20191001-1333.jar/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.startlevel_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.tracker_1.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.felix.scr_[2.1.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.promise_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.namespace_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework_1.8.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.wiring_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime.dto_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.540
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.dto_1.8.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.4.500.v20200225-0827 [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.update.configurator 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917 [3] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi_[3.13.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing dynamically imported package org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.6.100.v20191001-1333 [4] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.felix.scr_[2.1.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework_1.8.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.dto_1.8.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.namespace_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.startlevel_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.wiring_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime.dto_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.promise_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.555
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.tracker_1.5.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/equinox/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi_[3.13.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:../../../WTP/constellation.ratl.swg.usma.ibm.com/iesp2/ies-repositories/4.15/equinox/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.6.100.v20191001-1333.jar/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.startlevel_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.tracker_1.5.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.felix.scr_[2.1.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.promise_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.namespace_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework_1.8.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.wiring_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime.dto_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.dto_1.8.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.4.500.v20200225-0827 [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.update.configurator 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917 [3] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi_[3.13.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.10.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.571
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing dynamically imported package org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.6.100.v20191001-1333 [4] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.felix.scr_[2.1.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework_1.8.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.dto_1.8.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.namespace_1.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.startlevel_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.framework.wiring_1.2.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.service.component.runtime.dto_1.4.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.promise_1.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.osgi.util.tracker_1.5.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-03-01 05:42:38.587
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
An error has occurred. See the log file
E:\Test\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\rmc.product\1646142158140.log.
```

I have searched for similar error but found answers saying the eclipse used is very old which don't support java version. However in my case I verified that Eclipse 4.15 supports Java 8.

I also tried running RCP product file using "Launch an Eclipse Application" option but it too resulted in same error.

I was trying many things like changing features/Plug-ins in "Content", Start Levels in "Configuration" etc. but nothing did work. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you discard that launch configuration and create a new one by launching from your .product file, editing it afterward to further add any required plug-ins from your target. The appearance of "Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8" in the output is a giant red flag.

Comment: @nitind - Thank you for reply. I already tried creating totally new product file and new launch file as suggested but no luck. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: There were duplicate plugins in target platform. Removing duplicate plugins  resolved this issue.